# vtkImageViewer2 not rendering until I reset

Tags: vtk, dicom

I've showed a dicom image successfully with vtkImageviewer. Then I realized that vtkImageviewer2 would be more suitable, as I needed interactors and load images with slices, maybe 3d, etc

So I changed to **vtkImageviewer2**. Then I just see a white image. All white.

But my surprise was that, adding the render window interactor, **when I press r... the image appears!** So I looked into the class code. I saw the reset event and how it sets color window and color level. I've tried doing this, with poor results.

Why do I have to reset the window/level to see the image? I can do zoom, and rotate... around the white plane.

I did a *widget->Update()* or a *imageViewer->Render()* with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The Window Width/Level value is not computed initially, the default values are W255/L127.
It is necessary to set appropriate values. i.e. from Dicom Header Information or compute them by yourself.

```
myVtkImageViewer2->SetColorWindow(myWidthValue);
myVtkImageViewer2->SetColorLevel(myLevelValue);
```

Comment: I looked into the Dicom Header; got 1019.7251 and 1427.6089 for WindowCenter and WindowWitdh values. I set these on my vtkImageViewer2: the image appears with too much contrast, too obscure. I press the r button and... the image appears with less contrast. Anyway, with vtkImageViewer I didn't have to do any of this. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Setup window/level values from your vtkImageActor:

```
vtkImageActor->GetProperty()->SetColorWindow(20);
vtkImageActor->GetProperty()->SetColorLevel(10);
```